# c# windows form

Tags: c#

I have a handler that returns some string messages. How can i put them into a form application? I mean I would like each time the handler is activated to print the result in a windows form. I now i need to use thread. I don't know how can i programatically create and add changes the name of **the forms** that pop up when a message is handled. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Where are these handlers defined? Why do you believe you need to use threads? Please post your code and read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: because i want each time a handler is activated to pop up a form.

Comment: And why does this require threads?

Comment: Whics event in your app activates this handler? Where is handler originated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asssume that you have some work you want to do in the background and whenever an amount of progress is don you want to update the form...

Then I would use the backgroundworker:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
}



private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
    {
        if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            worker.ReportProgress((i * 10)); //Activating the progressChanged event
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you execute `worker.ReportProgress()` the event below will fire on the UI thread which is giving you the dynamic updates you wanted

```
private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.tbProgress.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%");
}
```

When the worker is finished executing the RunWorkerCompleted event will fire

```
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled == true))
    {
        this.tbProgress.Text = "Canceled!";
    }

    else if (!(e.Error == null))
    {
        this.tbProgress.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
    }

    else
    {
        this.tbProgress.Text = "Done!";
    }
}
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: where should i write this method? in main? how should i acces these methods?